# .Net Core integration tests with mock keeps returning null

Tags: asp.net-core, integration-testing

I am trying to be a good boy and write some unit and integration tests but I am slowly giving up. On the controller side, I have:

```
public class PointController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IPointL _pointL;

    public PointController(IMapper mapper, IPrincipal principal, IPointL pointL) : base(mapper, principal)
    {
        _pointL = pointL;
    }

    // GET: api/<PointController>
    /// <summary>
    /// Get point by id.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">Point id.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<PointDTO> GetPointAsync(int id)
    {
        // Get point.
        var pointModel = await _pointL.GetPointAsync(id);
        var pointDTO = _mapper.Map<PointDTO>(pointModel);

        return pointDTO;
    }
}
```

So the line `var pointModel = await _pointL.GetPointAsync(id);` in fact calls my logic layer:

```
public class PointL : BaseL, IPointL
{
    private readonly IBaseDAL _baseDAL;

    public PointL(IMapper mapper, IPrincipal principal, IBaseDAL baseDAL) : base(mapper, principal)
    {
        _baseDAL = baseDAL;
    }

    ///<inheritdoc/>
    public async Task<PointModel> GetPointAsync(int id)
    {
        _logger.Info($"Get point with id {id}.");

        var pointDBModel = await _baseDAL.GetPointAsync(id);
        if (pointDBModel is null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Point with id {id} not found.");
        }

        var pointModel = _mapper.Map<PointModel>(pointDBModel);

        return pointModel;
    }
}
```

which drops to the final, DAL layer with the `await _baseDAL.GetPointAsync(id);`

```
public partial class BaseDAL
{
    ///<inheritdoc/>
    public async Task<Point> GetPointAsync(int id)
    {
        _logger.Info($"Get point from database with id {id}.");

        using var dbGlistaContext = new GlistaContext(_options);
        var point = await dbGlistaContext.Point.FindAsync(id);

        return point;
    }
}
```

Now my plan was to write an integration test for the `GetPointAsync(int id)` method on the controller. I guess, this is the usual way or am I mistaken?
Either way, this is my not working attempt:

```
private readonly PointController _sut;
private readonly Mock<IPointL> _pointLMock = new Mock<IPointL>();
protected readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
protected readonly Mock<IPrincipal> _principalMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();

public PointControllerTests()
{
    _sut = new PointController(_mapperMock.Object, _principalMock.Object, _pointLMock.Object);
}

[Fact]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task GetPointAsync_ShouldReturnPoint_WhenPointExists()
{
    // Arrange.
    var pointId = 1;
    var pointModel = new PointModel
    {
        Id = pointId,
        Name = "T01",
    };
    _pointLMock.Setup(x => x.GetPointAsync(pointId))
        .ReturnsAsync(pointModel);

    // Act.
    var point = await _sut.GetPointAsync(pointId); // Keeps returning null no matter what! :(

    // Assert.
    Assert.Equal(pointId, point.Id);
}
```

This is for some reason NOT working as mock keeps returning null values! Does anybody have an idea why? I have watched some tutorials but I can't figure out the solution.

**EDIT:**

I was able to find out that the controller

```
        var pointModel = await _pointL.GetPointAsync(id);
        var pointDTO = _mapper.Map<PointDTO>(pointModel);
```

gets the `pointModel`, however, the mapping to DTO returns null. Thus I tried setting the mapper mock

```
var pointDTO = new PointDTO();
mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<PointModel, PointDTO>(It.IsAny<PointModel>())).Returns(pointDTO);
```

However, without any success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the `Map` method of the mapper mock object.

```
_mapperMock.Setup(x => x.Map<PointDTO>(It.IsAny<PointDTO>()))
    .Returns(...);
```

Comment: I tried `_mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<PointModel, PointDTO>(It.IsAny<PointModel>())).Returns(pointDTO);` but it still mapps to `null`.